# Prove that every maximal planar graph of order 4 or more is 3-connected

Tags: graph-theory

I thought I might be able to use the fact that for a maximal planar graph the minimum degree of the  graph is at least 3, but I couldn't figure anything out. Am I headed in the right direction? Where do i go from there?

Comment: What is "maximal planar"?

Comment: Adding an edge will make it nonplanar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any more detail is needed, my answer is based on [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15456-s10/Homeworks/hw3-answers.pdf).

---

If an edge $e$ of a maximal planar graph is in exactly two triangles then $G/e$ is also maximal planar. (Since $G/e$ has exactly three fewer edges.)

If $G$ is a maximal planar graph with $n \geq 4$ vertices then there are at least $n$ such edges. (Induction on $n$.)

Let $G$ be a maximal planar graph with at least four vertices. Assume that there are vertices $u,v$ such that $G-\{u,v\}$ is disconnected. Let $X$ be one component of $G-\{u,v\}$ and let $Y$ be another.

Contract edges of $G$ until you're left with just $u$ and $v$ along with one vertex of $X$ and one vertex of $Y$.

Since there are now only four vertices, we must be left with $K_4$. But then removing $u$ and $v$ can't disconnect the graph, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: I have a problem with your first statement.  If we remove an edge and the resulting graph is maximal planar, and then we add that edge back in, it is necessarily not maximal planar by the very definition of maximal planar.  You can't remove an edge from a maximal planar graph and have the resulting graph be maximal planar.

Comment: @user3440448: By $G/e$ I mean the graph obtained by contracting (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction) the edge $e$, not the graph obtained by deleting it. This gives a graph with one fewer vertices and three fewer edges.

Comment: Ah!  My apologies.

Comment: In the answer, I think something strange, at most  3 edges with the desired property are lost in the combining, leaving us with  |V_1| + |V_2| − 3 = n such edge , why not. |V_1| + |V_2| − 6

Answer (score -3):

This is not true.  Consider $G=(V, E)$, where $V=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $E=\{(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (1,4), (1,3)\}$.  If we remove nodes 1 and 3, the graph is not connected, thus $G$ is not 3-connected.

Comment: This graph isn't maximal planar (you can add an edge between 2 and 4).