# Prove that every plane triangulation has at least $n(n \ge 4)$ edges $e$ with the property that the only triangles containing $e$ are faces.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am trying to prove the following theorem.

**Theorem**  Every maximal planar graph of order 4 or more is 3 connected.

I looked up similar questions([prove-that-every-maximal-planar-graph-of-order-4-or-more-is-3-connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205538/prove-that-every-maximal-planar-graph-of-order-4-or-more-is-3-connected)) and found that Raoul provided a detailed answer [details.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15456-s10/Homeworks/hw3-answers.pdf) with the help of the following lemma.

**Lemma** Every plane triangulation with $n ≥ 4$ vertices has at least $n$ edges $e$ with the property that the only triangles containing $e$ are faces.

I did not understand one of the steps of the proof.

> Thus, **at most**  $3$ edges with the desired property are lost in the
> **combining**, leaving us with  $|V_1| + |V_2| − 3 = n$ such edges, as desired.

I feel that if all edges  on $t$   satisfy the property the only triangles containing them are faces
whether inside or outside.
Then it should become at least $|V_1| + |V_2| − 6$ in the combining not $|V_1| + |V_2| − 3$.

For example, in graph G below, we choose $C_3= uvw$, Any edge of the circle satisfies the condition in $C^{int}$ and $C^{out}$ but all lose the desired property in $G$.

[image]

If this lemma is incorrect, how should the theorem be proved?

In order to eliminate the confusion caused by the possible invalidation of the pdf file link, I re-copy the reference answer here.

> Fix an embedding of the triangulation.
>
> First, **we prove that every plane triangulation with  $n ≥ 4$
> vertices has at least $n$ edges $e$ with the property that the only
> triangles containing $e$ are faces**.  The proof is by induction on
> $n$ . The base is case is $K_4$ and holds trivially because all  $6$
> edges have this property.
>
> For the induction, pick any triangle $t$ that is not a face. We split
> the graph into two parts,  $G_1 = (V_1, E_1)$ and $G_2 = (V_2, E_2)$ ,
> where  $G_1$ is the induced graph on  $t$ and all of the vertices
> inside  $t$  in the embedding and $G_2$ is the induced graph on  $t$
> and all of the vertices outside $t$ . Both graphs are plane
> triangulations and both have fewer than n vertices. So, by induction,
> there are $|V_1| + |V_2| = n + 3$ edges in the two graphs with the
> desired property.  When we combine the graphs, the only edges that can
> lose this property are the edges of $t$ because no edges pass between
> any of the other vertices of  to any of the other vertices of $G_2$ .
> **Thus, at most  $3$ edges with the desired property are lost in the
> combining, leaving us with  $|V_1| + |V_2| − 3 = n$ such edges,** as
> desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the proof of the lemma is bad. The lemma might still be true, but I don't see how to prove it offhand.

I don't think we need the full power of the lemma. It's enough to show that:

**Lemma.** Every plane triangulation with $n \ge 4$ vertices has at least $6$ edges $e$ with the property that the only triangles containing $e$ are faces.

**Proof.** We do the same induction, except that $G_1$ and $G_2$ both contain $6$ of these edges. $3$ of those edges in $G_1$ might be edges of $t$ (so they don't count), and the same for $G_2$, but that still leaves $3$ edges in $G_1$ and $3$ in $G_2$ that do count, for a total of $6$. $\square$

We can carry out the proof that all plane triangulations with $n\ge 4$ vertices are $3$-connected, even if we only have the weaker version. All we need is that:

- If $\{u,v\}$ is a cut of $G$, then we don't contract edge $uv$.
- If we can partition $V(G)-\{u,v\}$ into $X \cup Y$ with no edges between $X$ and $Y$, then we shouldn't destroy the last vertex of $X$ or $Y$ (by contracting an edge incident to that vertex).

The first only excludes one edge at any moment. The second one doesn't constrain us at all unless $|X|=1$ or $|Y|=1$. But first of all, if $X = \{x\}$, that's at most two edges: $xu$ and $xv$ (and two more if $Y = \{y\}$). Second, I don't think that can actually happen, because at that point, the graph is pretty blatantly not a triangulation.

So having $6$ edges we can choose from to contract at any time is plenty to complete the proof.

Comment: I think the conditions are weakened very cleverly.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of the Lemma in the question is bogus, but I can prove something close, which is that there are at least $n-2$ edges that aren't in a separating triangle.  (I am not working too hard, so I could easily imagine getting $n$.)

You can't use such a simplistic inductive hypothesis.  To see why, consider gluing two $K_4$'s along a triangle. The claimed proof would say there are supposed to be $9$ edges that aren't in any non-facial triangle but there are only $6$.

To prove an ``$n-2$'' weakening of the Lemma, we need to do something like the following.  Let us call an edge of a triangulation $G$ *safe* if it is not in any separating triangle.  Say a triangulation $G$ is *secure* if every edge in it is safe.  And say that a face of a triangulation is *tricky* if it consists of only safe edges.

You can build any triangulation by starting from a secure triangulation and repeatedly gluing a secure triangulation into a face of what you have.  In a secure triangulation with $n$ vertices, there are $3n - 6$ safe edges, which we think of at $n + e$ with $e = 2n - 6$ and $t = 2n - 4$ tricky faces.  So $t\le e + 2$.

We are going to prove that, during a gluing move, the number of safe edges increases at least as much as the number of tricky faces. This means that we have $t \le e + 2$ at the end of the process. Since, certainly, $t\ge 0$, the number of safe edges $n + e\ge n - 2$.

Assume that we have a triangulation $G$ with $n$ vertices, $n + e$ safe edges and $t \le e$ tricky faces.  Let $H$ be a secure triangulation with $m$ vertices.  We need to track how the number of safe edges and tricky faces evolves.  To set notation, suppose that $T$ and $T'$ are the faces of $G$ and $H$ that are glued and that $G'$ is the resulting triangulation.

There are two cases: either $T$ is tricky or not.

Suppose that $T$ is tricky. Then the number of safe edges in $G'$ is
$$
n + e + 3m - 6 - 6 = (n + m - 3) + e + 2m - 9
$$
where the lhs comes from the fact that $H$ is secure, so it all of its $3m - 6$ edges are safe.  We lose three safe edges from $G$ and three from $H$ in the gluing.  The point of the rhs is that the number of vertices in $G'$ is $n + m - 3$, so the excess increases by $2m - 9$.  (This may be negative, which is why we must be careful.)

Now we look at how many new tricky faces we get.  There are
$$
2m - 4 - 4 - 1 = 2m - 9
$$
which comes from observing that $H$ has $2m -4$ faces, all of which are tricky.  One, $T'$ is removed in the gluing, and three stop being tricky, because the edges of $T'$ are not safe in $G'$.  Additionally, $T$ is not a face in $G'$, so we lose one tricky face from $G$.

The increase in the excess and number of tricky faces match, so this case is complete.

Now we assume that $T$ is not tricky.  Counting in a similar way, we conclude that there are at least
$$
n + e + 3m - 6 - 5 = (n + e - 3) + e + 2m - 8
$$
safe edges in $G'$, where we have $-5$ instead of $-6$ because at least one edge of $T$ was already unsafe, so it isn't removed from the count when we glue.  Hence, the excess increased by at least $2m - 8$.

Moving to the question of tricky faces, this time we get
$$
2m - 4 - 4  = 2m - 8
$$
new tricky faces, since removing $T$ from $G$ doesn't change this count.

Since both cases work out, we are done.